# Not able to outer join two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code to merge two dataframe :
`pd.concat(df1, df2, on='a', how='outer')`

I am getting the following error:-

> TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2], on='a', how='outer')

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='a', how='outer')
```

But also [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is possible - it return default outer join by index of both `DataFrames`, so added `[]` and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('a'), df2.set_index('a')], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try the `merge` method.

`pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='a')`

Comment: Also the concat method mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat

Here's the documentation for concat. As you can see, there is no 'on' (or how) arg, so you just need to adjust your parameters accordingly.